# How to get the selected value from Jlist in Java no matter how many times the Jlist is clicked

Tags: java, swing

I wish to be able to make my JList respond to a click even when it is pressed more than once.Value changed is called only when another index is clicked.This is the default behaviour.However,i Want it to always tell when a click occurs.From this simple example,it is clear that the value changed will be fired only if i click it once,clicking it twice will not respond.I need this specific functionality,The main reason is legitimate but more complex to explain.

```
public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TestFrame frame = new TestFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public TestFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JList list = new JList();

        list.setModel(new AbstractListModel() {
            String[] values = new String[] {"one", "two", "three"};
            public int getSize() {
                return values.length;
            }
            public Object getElementAt(int index) {
                return values[index];
            }
        });

        list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                System.out.println("selected index : "+list.getSelectedIndex());

            }


        });

        contentPane.add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use a MouseListener to solve this:

```
  list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
     @Override
     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int index = list.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
        System.out.println("MouseListener index: " + index);
     }
  });
```

Comment: @JanyGwan: y/w, but note also that all info was found in the [JList API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html).

Comment: Yes,i am using a Jaccordion api which insisted that  my cardlayout panel should be selected based on valueChanged functionality.I used the mouse even now and it still worked.I actually almost said it has to be in the valueChanged function until i tried the mouse event.Thanks again!